# Правильно ли я отображаю только заполненные свойства товара?

Tags: php, битрикс

Я хочу чтобы отображались только заполненные свойства товара(с заполненными VALUE) на детальной странице товара,
пытаюсь использовать этот код, но тогда это свойство c пустым значением всё равно отображается

```
<? if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['CML2_ARTICLE']){?>
<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["NAME"]?>
<? echo $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["VALUE"]?>
<?}?>
```

А остальные свойства без проверки на пустое значение вывожу так и всё работает

```
<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["NAME"]?>
<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["VALUE"]?>
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `<? if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['CML2_ARTICLE']['VALUE']){?>`?

Comment: @u_mulder я не понимаю вашего комментария

Comment: "Это печально."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам ответ написал [u_mulder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178087/u-mulder) ,но очень странно

В итоге для отображения только заполненных свойств нужно добавить в условие VALUE и получить в итоге код

```
<? if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['ВАШЕСВОЙСТВО']["VALUE"]){?>
<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["ВАШЕСВОЙСТВО"]["NAME"]?>
<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["ВАШЕСВОЙСТВО"]["VALUE"]?>
<?}?>
```